# howto pass dictionary key in a form event C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

Here is the code that I am running:

```
private Dictionary<string, List<GuiEvent>> m_events = new Dictionary<string, List<GuiEvent>>();
        private void OnRadioBtnCheckedChange(object sender, EventArgs e, string formhandle)
        {
            RadioButton control = (RadioButton)sender;
            GuiEvent evnt = new GuiEvent
            {
                id = GuiEventType.RadioButtonChange,
                ElementName = control.Name,
                sparam = control.Text,
                lparam = control.Checked ? 1 : 0
            };
            m_events[formhandle].Add(evnt);
        }
```

Getting the error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0123  No overload for 'OnRadioBtnCheckedChange' matches delegate 'EventHandler'   MtGuiController C:\Users\AIMS-RESEARCH\Desktop\MtGuiController\MtGuiController\Controller.cs    258 Active
```

Previously when the `m_event` was declared like this:

```
private List<GuiEvent> m_events = null;
```

And the function:

```
private void OnRadioBtnCheckedChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton control = (RadioButton)sender;
    GuiEvent evnt = new GuiEvent
    {
        id = GuiEventType.RadioButtonChange,
        ElementName = control.Name,
        sparam = control.Text,
        lparam = control.Checked ? 1 : 0
    };
    m_events.Add(evnt);
}
```

Everything was working fine.
I am not able to understand what I can do in this situation. I cannot declare `string formhandle` as global as it is changing every time. So please take a note of it. It is C# DLL function.

Can anybody tell me solution that will help?

Comment: What is formhandle? You cannot change the signature of the event handler delegate.

Comment: every event can be handled by a handler with specific signature. You can not have handler with different signature. That's why you are getting this error. What value you want to be of `formhandle` when checkbox is check?

Comment: `No overload for 'OnRadioBtnCheckedChange' matches delegate 'EventHandler'` means that signature of function does not match signature of delegate - i.e. number or types of function parameters don't match those of delegate (think about delegate as a blueprint for functions). You cannot just add parameters or change their types. Explain better what is `formhandle` and how it is related to radio button checked changing.

Comment: @devcrp formhandle is the string that will help me maintain a dictionary with key value pair. It keeps changing in the application, hence I cannot set it to global scope

Comment: The easiest method is to crate a new class the inherits the radio button : public class MyRadioButton : RadioButton.  Then you can add properties to MyRadioButton.  I often do this with Buttons so I can add a row and column property.

Comment: You could store a key into the `Tag` property of the `RadioButton`.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Can you please tell me whether it can be done dynamically? or has to be specified in manually in the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use some additional information in your event handler, you cannot pass it as an additional parameter to event handling function. You cannot also change type of event handler parameters - it should just accept two arguments - `sender` and `EventArgs`.

You have three options here. First - store data in `sender` and then access that data in event handler. Simplest way is using radio button's tag. [Control.Tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag?view=netcore-3.1) is inherited from base `Control` class and you can use it to store some data when you create control. I.e. assign appropriate `formhandle` to every radio button `Tag` (you can even do that manually via designer)

```
radioButton1.Tag = "foo";
radioButton2.Tag = "bar";
```

and then retrieve it in event handler:

```
    private void OnRadioBtnCheckedChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton control = (RadioButton)sender;
        GuiEvent evnt = new GuiEvent
        {
            id = GuiEventType.RadioButtonChange,
            ElementName = control.Name,
            sparam = control.Text,
            lparam = control.Checked ? 1 : 0
        };
        var formhandle = (string)control.Tag; // here you get "foo" or "bar"
        m_events[formhandle].Add(evnt);
    }
```

Second option - create your custom radio button control. But that's overkill here. Usually, you do that when you need a custom look & feel, not just to pass data.

Third option - lookup data you want using the data you have (e.g. control name). This option makes sense when data you need is not available at the time of control creation or if it changes over time.